# How do I save Virtual Machine state in UTM (QEMU)? using M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I am a beginner in dealing with virtual machines. I have managed to boot up a virtual machine (Ubuntu) using UTM on my M1 Macbook Pro. However, I have been having a hard time figuring out how I can save the state of the virtual machine so that I can free up my computer's resources and still be able to pick up where I left off on my Ubuntu VM in UTM. So, I would really appreciate anyone that knows or has any ideas as to how I can accomplish this.

I would also like to add that when I am booting up my Ubuntu VM on UTM, so choose to trial Ubuntu rather than install it.

Comment: "trial rather than install?" I'm not sure I grasp the difference. How do you trial freeware?

Answer (score 1):

There is one [suspend option](https://mac.getutm.app/guide/#suspend) however, that works only if all non-removable drives are of QCOW2 type drive images AND the guest and host architecture are same. Otherwise, it will be booting up fresh!